# Why can't I castle on Arena chess?

Tags: castling, arena

I play chess a lot against Arena (the GUI thing),
but I can't seem to castle.
The requirements for castling are met, just the castling itself doesn't work.
I'm on windows.

Comment: Castling is definitely possible using Arena. Are you *certain* the requirements for castling were all met when you couldn't do it?

Comment: @ETD my rook never moved, my king never moved, the king wasn't in check nor would he be if I castled him. I think I did something wrong when attempting to castle... how do I castle on Arena???

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs Could you add a picture with the position to the question?

Comment: I made a custom scenario to make sure the requirements are met: http://puu.sh/nm6Ck/d56b2e6b8f.jpg

Comment: Try to move the King to its target square.  The Rook may automagically land on the right square to complete the Castling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record (adapted from my comment above): as with other such interfaces, if you move the King to its target square, the corresponding Rook will automagically land on the right square to complete the Castling.  (A move like Ke1-g1 or Ke8-c8 can only mean Castling.  Usually the computer will refuse the move if Castling is illegal for some reason.)